# How to control the pages of a PDF file for iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an app to show some local PDF files to the user.

The app has 2 functions:

- Show the local PDF (pdf viewer).
- Make an "Interactive summary" so the user can navigate between the pages of the PDF.

In Android I'm using 'PDF.JS' plugin for xamarin, to show all the pdf files and it is working fine. I can easily open the PDF in the page I want by using the "Interactive summary".

On the other hand, in IOS I'm using a `webview` to show the pdf. The only problem is when creating the "Interactive Summary" for IOS I can't figure out how to open the PDF file in the page I want. There is any library or function that grants me access to it (pdf pages)?

I'm attaching some screenshots of the code so you guys can understand what's happening.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you paste in the code snippets instead of screenshots?  Please refer to the markdown help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Syncfusion PDF](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfpdfviewer/getting-started).

It has already all the functionalities you want:

```
 <Grid x:Name="pdfViewGrid">
        <syncfusion:SfPdfViewer x:Name="pdfViewerControl" InputFileStream="{Binding PdfDocumentStream}"/>
    </Grid>
```

To change the page:

```
<Button x:Name="goToNextButton"  Grid.Column="3" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Image="PageDown.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Command="{Binding GoToNextPageCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=pdfViewerControl}}"/>

<Button x:Name="goToPreviousButton" Grid.Column="4" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Image="PageUp.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Command="{Binding GoToPreviousPageCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=pdfViewerControl}}"/>
```

Comment: Can i use Syncfusion for comercial purpose for free?

Comment: They have a community license check their page https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense